# Link to call a method in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a tweet scaffold(controllers, models,views,..) in my Rails 3 app and among all the usual controller methods I have a 'tweet' method in my TweetsController. In my views, among the 'edit' and 'delete' links, I want a 'tweet' link, so this link should post the message to Twitter. Because when I simply create a tweet, it does't go to twitter directly, it remains listed in tweets/index.html.erb, it goes only to twitter if I click the tweet button. Can you help me? I think I should somehow point the link to the tweet method in TweetsController.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: def tweet
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  client.update @tweet
  redirect_to root_path
  flash[:notice] = 'Message tweeted!'
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. To get this thing done, I wrote the following:

*First, add in config/routes.rb:****

get 'tweet/:id', :as => 'tweet', :to => "tweets#tweet"

*Then, add in your view:*
<%= link_to 'tweet', "tweet/#{tweet.id}" %>

Done!